# Node child_process spawn hangs when calling git shortlog -sn

Tags: node.js, git, command-line-interface, child-process, spawn

### My Scenario

In my node application I'm using [child_process.spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) to query information from the current repository

I've built a small function to return a promise which resolves with the response from the command:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const gitExec = command => (
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const thread = spawn('git', command);
    const stdOut = [];
    const stdErr = [];

    thread.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      stdOut.push(data.toString('utf8'));
    });

    thread.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      stdErr.push(data.toString('utf8'));
    });

    thread.on('close', () => {
      if (stdErr.length) {
        reject(stdErr.join(''));
        return;
      }
      resolve(stdOut.join());
    });
  })
);

module.exports = gitExec;
```

Calling `git branch`works just as expected:

```
gitExec(['branch'])
.then((branchInfo) => {
  console.log(branchInfo);
})
```

(as expected) results in

```
    * develop
      feature/forever
      feature/sourceconfig
      feature/testing
      master
```

From my understanding this proves the method I'm using to actually be working.

When calling `git shortlog -sn` the spawned process "hangs" and does not resolve in anything

```
gitExec(['shortlog', '-sn'])
.then((shortlogInfo) => {
  console.log(shortlogInfo);
})
```

Calling `git shortlog -sn` via commandline i geht the expected result:

```
   154  Andreas Gack
    89  Some other dude
     6  Whoever else
```

### My (so far unsuccessfull) tries

using [spawnSync](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options) (while changing my gitExec function to acommodate the syncronous approach) returns an object as documented - so the process seems to actually exit - but the relevant props of the object `output` `stdout` and `stderr` are all empty.
The `status` of the object is `0` which indicates the command to execute successfully

I've read about having to redefine the `maxBuffer` in the spawn options, but neither setting it to a (ridiculously) high value nor a very small value does make a difference in the syncronous or asynchronous approach.

Setting the `shell` option to `true` also does not make a difference in all of the above scenarios.

The issue occurrs on my Win10x64 as well as on MacOs running node v6.9.x or 7.x

Also calling the alias `git log --pretty=short` does not provide a result

### My Actual Question

- Has anyone yet managed to successfully query `git shortlog -sn` via child_process.spawn?
- Does anyone know a module for Node which allows querying the current local git-repository?

I somehow think the two commands `git branch` and `git shortlog` internally handle their output in a different way.

I'd be happy to create an issue on their github page, but I actually don't know how to identify the actual root-cause of that problem.

Any further input is much appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`git shortlog` thinks it needs to read something from `stdin` thats why the whole process hangs. To work around that, you can pass `stdin` from the main process in as an option and pipe everything else as usual. Then it should run.

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const gitExec = command => (
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const thread = spawn('git', command, { stdio: ['inherit', 'pipe', 'pipe'] });
    const stdOut = [];
    const stdErr = [];

    thread.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      stdOut.push(data.toString('utf8'));
    });

    thread.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      stdErr.push(data.toString('utf8'));
    });

    thread.on('close', () => {
      if (stdErr.length) {
        reject(stdErr.join(''));
        return;
      }
      resolve(stdOut.join());
    });
  })
);

module.exports = gitExec;
```

Perhaps some more context from the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog):

> If no revisions are passed on the command line and either **standard input is not a terminal** or there is no current branch, git shortlog will output a summary of the log read from standard input, without reference to the current repository.

Which is the case when spawning a child process. So it expects something gets passed in via `stdin`. By setting `stdin` to the main process `git shortlog` is aware of the terminal and therefor will run.

Comment: This does not seem to work unfortunately.
what (kind of) works is `['ignore', 'pipe', 'pipe']` . Yet this leaves me with an empty response.

what also confuses me is thet `git shortlog -sn` does not require any input when called over regular console

Comment: This seems to be a Windows problem then? Unfortunately, I don't have a Windows system to test any further :/

Comment: Okay, I just found a Windows 10 installation and tried to confirm that `git shortlog -sn` didn't require any input. What console were you trying?

Comment: I tested on a "regular" windows command prompt as well as the console integrated in my IDE (Webstorm)
Did `git shortlog -sn` require input for you?

Comment: Yeah, it does prompt me for input if I run the command in a non-git directory. Git version is 2.12

Comment: Do you run the script via `npm run` by any chance?

Comment: Yup. That was/is the problem. `npm` somehow "hides" the stdin from it's child process which is the node process itself.

While I still don't know how to solve the actual problem (not getting the output of `git shortlog`) at least I know the reason.

I'll also investigate further on this and post an update if I find a solution.

Many thanks for your help here!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by specifying the before and after commit hashes.

```
git shortlog -sn `git log --pretty=format:'%H' --reverse | head -1` `git log --pretty=format:'%H' | head -1`"
```